# Triggering a function on multiple events

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, triggers

I've written some code to collapse 2 columns if the text on the left is longer than the image on the right:

```
var collapsed = null;
var banner = function() {
    var txt = $('.banner .text').outerHeight();
    var image = $('.banner .main-image').outerHeight();
    if (txt > image) {
        // Collapse columns
        $('.banner').addClass('single-line');
        // Set the breakpoint the column collapsed at
        if (collapsed == null) {
            collapsed = $(window).width();
        }
    }

    // Restore the 2 columns when the browser hits the breakpoint
    if ($(window).width() >= collapsed) {
        $('.banner').removeClass('single-line')
    }
}
```

My problem is getting this function to trigger at the right times.  This works:

```
$(window).resize(banner);
```

But neither of these work...

```
$(window).onload(banner); // When the page first loads
$(window).on('orientationchange', banner); // When device is rotated
```

I could be completely on the wrong tracks here, so please feel free to point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "But neither of these work"? Does it not resize as you're expecting? Does your function get called at all?

Comment: The function is firing, but it's not resizing as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Acording to the documentation of JQuery,there is no "onload" method for the jquery object, instead you should use "ready":

```
$(window).ready(banner);
```

About this line not getting fired, probably because you"re using the wrong synthax. The reference for "on" method :

.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )

so you should try this :

```
$(window).on('orientationchange','window', banner)
```

Cheers

Comment: I've changed the `onload` method to `load` I had already noticed the error in the console. the function is firing, its just not resizing as expected

Answer (score 0):

To run when the page first load, you can use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    banner();
});
```

Regarding the `orientationchange` event, make sure you are using the jquery.mobile.js (https://api.jquerymobile.com/orientationchange/)